# Virtual environment vs separate interpretor

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've read a few things that said you should set up separate virualenv for each project - I mean it makes sense for compartmentalization and all that.

I also recently came across a solution that said to use separate interpreters for each project.
My question is: which is better? And what are advantages/disadvantages for each solution?

I should also add that I'm using Eclipse for this rather than a command line.

Comment: Only if testing across major python verssions, like py3.4 vs py2.7. Even so, if you have different virtualenvs all using the same version, they all utilize the **same** interpreter

Comment: @reptilicus - The solution I read suggested importing a new interpreter (for example Python 3.5) and naming it "Python35_MyProject", and carry on with this convention each time a new project is made.